# page not found : / Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I want to add new url but I got this error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 14, 2020 - 20:19:51
Django version 2.2.2, using settings 'cineam.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /
```

here is my url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ticketing import urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ticketing/', include(urls))
]
```

ticketing/urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path

from ticketing.views import cinema_list

urlpatterns=[
    path('movies/list/', cinema_list),
]
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which URL you were trying to access.I assume you were trying to access localhost:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/. in this case you will get this error "Page NOT FOUND."
Try this and then try accessing the same URL again, It will work

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ticketing import urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("ticketing.urls"))
]
```

else if you were accessing localhost:8000/ticketing/ it will still bring the error because
you have not pointed which urls.py file you are trying to access. In that case...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ticketing import urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ticketing/', include("ticketing.urls"))
]
```